# To fill item field from another list item field

Tags: list

I need to create the following.
There is Tasks list with the fields Full Name (lookup from Contacts list), Username (type Person or Group), Manager (type Person or Group)
In the Contact list, each employee has a field Full Name,  Username (type Person or Group), Manager (type Person or Group).
Thus when choosing Full Name in the Tasks list, automatically filled fields Username and Manager with the same values ​​as in the Contacts list.
Can someone know how to do this using jquery or maybe there is something more simple?

I found what I need here
http://coresharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-spservices-to-query-list-in.html
But I can't understand where in the page code I need to put this script.
Also in this example, only one field with the choice - City1, but what I need to add to the script if I have more fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to duplicate data from Contacts list fields Username and Manager, you just can choose them as additional fields in the properties of your lookup field FullName.
Then this two fields will be filled automatically, when you'll choose Full Name.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Update List Item" action from the sharepoint designer...